# Multiselect list in visualforce page not passing all values to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, multi-select, form

I have a select list set to mutliselect in a Visualforce page. However, when i go to save the records only the first ten selected values are returned.

This an example debug before saving:

```
10:52:16:273 USER_DEBUG [151]|DEBUG|this.day (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...)
```

Is there any reason for it to be cut off?

```
                    <apex:selectList value="{!day}" size="8" multiselect="true" style="width:240px"   styleClass="slds-select daysmonth"  >
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="6" itemLabel="6"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="7" itemLabel="7"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="8" itemLabel="8"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="9" itemLabel="9"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="11" itemLabel="11"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="12" itemLabel="12"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="13" itemLabel="13"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="14" itemLabel="14"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="15" itemLabel="15"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="16" itemLabel="16"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="17" itemLabel="17"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="18" itemLabel="18"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="19" itemLabel="19"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="20" itemLabel="20"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="21" itemLabel="21"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="22" itemLabel="22"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="23" itemLabel="23"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="24" itemLabel="24"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="25" itemLabel="25"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="26" itemLabel="26"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="27" itemLabel="27"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="28" itemLabel="28"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="29" itemLabel="29"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="30" itemLabel="30"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="31" itemLabel="31"/>
                </apex:selectList>
```

using a string[] in the controller

```
public String[] day { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you try system.debug('@@@@'+JSON.serialize(this.day))

Comment: @DanielHowell - When you say only the first 10 are returned, are you talking about the debug log or the actual Select input on the page? If you are talking the debug log then that is normal as it is truncated to save space